# How to install laravel on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, composer-php

**Resolved:** I have installed Laravel using composer on my local machine in XAMPP environment.
Now I am going to do it on server. I have an AWS instance, I had tried to install composer using these steps.

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Its execute successfully. Now any of the composer command is not working:-

```
composer install
composer create-project laravel/laravel sujeetlaraveldemo
```

**Solution**
Thanks google, Got the answer, Its

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

composer install
We need to move composer.phar to bin directory.

Comment: as someone coming here from Google and seeing a downvote. Please give a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks google,
Got the answer, Its

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

composer install
```

We need to move composer.phar to bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the composer documentation [on their website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

The command you have mentioned does not actually install the Composer globally. It just downloads composer.phar executable to the folder you are currently in.

If you have got to your /laravel_project  folder and downloaded the composer inside you can use it writing "php composer.phar" instead of "composer" like that:

> php composer.phar install

Comment: Calling `./composer.phar` will execute it in the current directory as well, provided it has the x bit set.

Answer (score 0):

This is in case anyone uses this question as a reference.
Make sure you have the composer.json file in the home/ec2-user folder before installing composer.
Use this to create the initial composer.json file.

```
$ cd ~
$ nano composer.json
```

Paste this

```
{
 "require": {
  "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
      }
 }

CTRL + O -> Save
CTRL + X -> Exit
```

Then paste these commands.

```
  $ cd ~
    $ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
    $ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

then you can run

```
 $ sudo composer install
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try any Manage Hosting providers because its manage your server easily just type on google manage hosting keywords you found many options